# Matlab GUI, how to display result in listbox gui like command windows

Tags: matlab, listbox, matlab-guide

i write code for generate the result in command window

```
fprintf('                      Maximum Power Mismatch = %g \n', maxerror)

head =['    Bus  Voltage  Angle    ------Load------    ---Generation---   Injected'
       '    No.  Mag.     Degree     MW       Mvar       MW       Mvar       Mvar '
       '                                                                          '];
disp(head)
for n=1:nbus
     fprintf(' %5g', n), fprintf(' %7.3f', Vm(n)),
     fprintf(' %8.3f', deltad(n)), fprintf(' %9.3f', Pd(n)),
```

what the listing for generate the result in gui listbox

sorry i can post longer listing than this

here my file .fig and .m file if you wanna try, you can change listbox with multiline edit textbox or table, i just wanna display the result in gui

[matlab file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dxy49nxr14kgeb4/pflow.rar?dl=0)

*Note : fill basemva = 100, accuracy = 0.001 , max iter = 100 , accelaration = 1.8*

thx

Comment: can you explain bit more what kind of list box you mean ? did you meant [1] kind of interactive list box ?
[1] http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/interactive-list-box-in-a-guide-gui.html

Comment: the listing above to show result in command windows, but i want to show the result in listbox gui, with multiline and looping

Comment: Refer following stackoverflow[1] suggested answer and try to adapt it to your scenario. I think it'll be helpful. As i understood if you add necessary values to data variable properly it'll show up on gui list.
(i don't have matlab at this moment so couldn't try it myself :) )
[1] - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11493798/populating-a-matlab-gui-listbox-from-database-values

Comment: are you sure you want to do that in a `listbox` ? ... Don't you mean a multiline `textbox` ? (_or a_ `table` _maybe ?_)

Comment: anything that can display result like this in GUI

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a [multicolumn listbox?](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/42670-multi-column-listbox/content/uimulticollist.m)

*Note: Since we dont have your variables - we cant run your example code to see what it looks like in the commandline.*